# How can I insert a Fragment into a Layout xml file?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an Android Layout file, and a Fragment class. How can I add the Fragment to the layout file?

**Android Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="346dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/botonera_registradora_bg"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
...
==> here I need to put my fragment
...
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment class**

```
public class PanelDerechoLowerFragment extends Fragment {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FrameLayout in the XML. Then you'll have to add the fragment in programmatically in an activity.

The Activity would be associated with your RelativeLayout, the fragment would have its own layout.

Like so,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="346dp"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/botonera_registradora_bg"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal">

  <FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now load your fragment like this:-

```
     ItemDetailFragment itemDetailFragment=new ItemDetailFragment();

      FragmentTransaction transaction = 
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

transaction.setCustomAnimations(animSlideIn, animSlideOut, animSlideIn, animSlideOut);
transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).replace(R.id.frameLayout, itemDetailFragment)
        .commitAllowingStateLoss();`
```